# Are Scihub or Mega/Google Docs articles allowed on CV?

Tags: discussion

Was just curious about this question today because I have sometimes seen that people here will ask for article links which include whatever is relevant to their statistical questions. Sometimes this isn't an option because there is a paywall. Because there isn't a way to upload the pdf directly, this prohibits people sometimes from sharing a link that would elucidate whatever statistical questions the OP will have.

Some ways I considered to get around this are Scihub and some open repository like Mega or Google Docs. The problem with Scihub is that it is technically journal piracy, so I imagine that option is not legal for CV. For sites like Mega or Google Docs, one can host their *legally* obtained documents online, but I assume one cannot disseminate them to a wider audience unless there is some kind of licensing agreement that allows this.

I guess my question is this: what is the best way to share links behind paywalls and are the options above available on CV?

Comment: We moderators lack the specialized knowledge to adjudicate  legal claims. Rights-holders can engage with Scihub/etc. to sort out their copyright claims. The important thing to keep in mind is that **a link to an article is not enough** -- links die. We need the full citation information to replace the article if the link goes dead. And ideally, the question or answer should explain what part of the article is being asked about, or summarize the content that answers the question. Otherwise, the question/answer may have little, if any, utility in the absence of the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice question.

Problem is we often befuddle between what is *illegal* and what is *unethical* (see this [discussion](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4624)).

One thing is clear though: we need proper, clear citation to any work/pre-print/literature. Those should be coupled with DOI, arXiv identifier or whichever applies to the work concerned. These would ensure once a link dies/rots, future users can still seek the required paper.

Coming to the bone of contention: should we cite Sci-hub/lib-gen or other such repositories?

See, it's an open secret that many people around the world (especially South-Asian countries) use these resources and at least it would not be too much to say that even more people are getting or already are acquainted with such resources. So, if they *need*, they would *resort* to such resources, irrespective of whether one explicitly includes such links. Personally, while I admit even I use Sci-hub, I never cite them. While I cannot forbid others, I think it's apt to not engage in such practice of using resources likes Sci-hub in our posts here.

Why? Because it can be political and there can be uncharted legal issues not explored/beyond our knowledge:

> ... a link to Sci-Hub is, itself, a radical expression of personal politics. In keeping with our desire to minimise the expression of party/personal politics here, I would therefore recommend avoiding such links.

Pertaining to legal issues, one can check these related posts and links therein:

[What should I do when I see copyright violations posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114919/what-should-i-do-when-i-see-copyright-violations-posted-on-stack-overflow) (SO)

[What to do when a post contains a "suspicious" link (possibly with copyrighted material)?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3953/what-to-do-when-a-post-contains-a-suspicious-link-possibly-with-copyrighted-m) (MO)

Comment: +1 for the insightful answer. However the second question still remains somewhat unclear...is it okay for us to host the document online somewhere if we have correctly sourced it? I lean towards not doing that for keeping myself outta trouble (by just citing the document like I normally do), but I'm wondering if its totally wrong to share the doc online in the first place.

Comment: Please check this Law.SE thread: [Is it legal to share digital copies of copyrighted material by allowing access to my cloud drive?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/95834/is-it-legal-to-share-digital-copies-of-copyrighted-material-by-allowing-access-t).

Answer (score 8):

Agreeing with [User1865345's answer](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6638/17230), I'd say best practice is to:—

- Give a full reference, including name & title. That's a fail-safe in case of link-rot, & an aid to recognition.
- Link to the DOI, or if there isn't one, somewhere like JSTOR, arXiv, PubMed, &c. That reduces the risk of link-rot; & spares people having to download a PDF file before they even know if they want to read the whole paper, in the (typical) case that the site provides an abstract, or some kind of preview.

You may still wish to add another link; though, as [Sycorax points out](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6637/are-scihub-or-mega-google-docs-articles-allowed-on-cv#comment22729_6637), links oughtn't to be essential to understanding a question or answer, so it's all right if the first link isn't immediately accessible to everyone. If you do, & don't know if you might be infringing copyright, or somehow abetting infringement, consider the following:

- The law. IANAL, but I imagine you are infringing copyright if you make available a complete article & you're not the copyright owner & don't have their permission (either specifically or through a general license). I've no idea about linking to copyright-infringing material that someone else put up. (In either case I believe the copyright owner may issue a D.M.C.A. take-down notice.)
- S.E.'s current [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public). The 'Acceptable Use Policy' says you mustn't "post content that infringes on another’s intellectual property right, including [...] copyright". Don't know if 'posting' can mean 'linking to'.
- Current site policy: see [Links to copyright material](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5196/17230). For articles, at any rate, the consensus seems to be that it's not for other users to bother themselves about anyone's possible infringement of someone else's copyright.
- Readers' sensibilities: it would be courteous to avoid *direct* links to potentially copyright-infringing material; better they land on a page that describes the content & leaves them the choice. If some might consider a particular site disreputable, I'd recommend making the target clear in the link text.