Should we flag a question that links to a scanned copy of a book?
It happens from time to time that a question, an answer or a comment links to a (scanned) pdf of a book (or a paper, but book seems esp. problematic). I write a comment asking the author to fix their post/comment as providing links to pdfs of copy-righted material seems illegal.
Should I flag such posts instead?
Related: Am I allowed to attach PDFs of papers to questions?

Recent example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/657327/237901. And this thread ended up as a Hot Network Question.

Closely related: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6692/22311

Also https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5196/17230. I took from that we'd be all right drawing the line at links to copies of whole books (in infringement of copyright) - no harm in re-starting the discussion though. Note that this is (was?) a contentious topic, & my answer there something of a compromise.

@Scortchi I apologize for missing this thread; it is indeed relevant. Going forward, I will not flag links to book copies (I haven't done so anyway) and, when I can, I'll made an edit and leave a comment for the author of the post to explain why. They can always revert the change if they don't agree.

@dipetkov: Well, that is flaggable, but if you're happy to edit in a better link, that's no more than I'd do. Not sure I'd bother raising the issue of potential copyright infringement though. Other issues with that link you provide as an example are that (1) there's no guarantee of its stability, (2) it's directly to a PDF, & (3) the PDF is a scanned image - hard to search for text, & useless to people reliant on screen-readers.

I regard such practice as unethical but -- if we are being pragmatic -- as beyond our scope as a community. We are not an amateur police force nor guardians of morality.
I am fine with you or anyone else commenting individually on that. It's possible that sometimes such behaviour is just clueless. More likely, someone would say: It wasn't me who scanned it, but given that it exists, it is accessible. And so on.
This view is related to my reactions on finding scanned copies of my own work here and there that breach copyright. I don't have the time, the energy, or the inclination to chase up such behaviour and guess that it would usually be futile to do that. Very often it is difficult at best to find out who posted something and who is in a position to take it down. At worst I would lay myself open to abuse. I take away a small positive that someone else is interested in my work.
There is behaviour we want to deal with severely, especially spam and hateful or insulting posts or comments that undermine the smooth and civilised work of this site. Bad actors don't deserve a voice here. But we can frown upon much behaviour without being zealous about seeking it out. That is not to mention trying to improve or remove the poor or very poor questions which (rightly as well as wrongly) consume much of the attention of moderators and the most active members.
An important dimension here is that flagging puts an onus on the moderators at least to read and consider such flags. I am not a moderator and am in awe of the commitment and energy the moderators put into this site. I wouldn't want to burden them with policing such behaviour, or to come up with criteria for deciding which referencing is acceptable and which not. Naturally the moderators can and should speak for themselves.
There is much on CV or SE that is at choice for individuals. For example, I put some effort into correcting small language and other mistakes in questions and answers, and I would not do that if I didn't think it improved the site on balance, or if in a strong sense I didn't enjoy it, in about the same way that many gardeners enjoy weeding. But I strongly recognise and respect that many active members have no time or taste for that. In short, do keep up your lobbying using comments to try to improve standards.

I've noticed that you care about language and "zealous" is too strong a word for what I've been doing esp. since it has a negative connotation. I don't seek out those links; I just notice them from time to time. I asked whether I should flag because I don't want to create extra work for anyone. I've got the privilege to edit posts, so perhaps I'll go ahead and do that. I can't do anything about comments but then not many people read them.

"zealous" is not pejorative in my usage. I often read comments here: it's quite common that the comments are the most interesting -- or even the most entertaining -- part of many threads. I don't really subscribe to the SE philosophy that comments are ultimately trivial and transient.  Naturally you can edit as well as comment, but what does that mean? Would you seek to replace a dubious link with a better one?

Fixed the post that got me thinking about this (again) with a link to GoodReads. Maybe Google Books is better but it may be confusing that it's country specific. For example, I get redirected to books.google.de.

(+1 to Nick Cox, as always). As an editor, I often provide a general link in place of a scanned pdf like the one stated -- mostly the publishers link (I don't prefer a link to an online shopping site like Amazon) of the copyright material. With all ethical and other technical (possibly legal) arguments aside, those who really want to use the material will find one way or other to have the possession of a scanned/digital copy, to one's chagrin (if there is). And this doesn't fall within the purview of the community here to be vigilant to check those practices.

@dipetkov, There is a site maintained by the author of the book, for which you provided the Goodreads link, for that book's purpose (data set, errata, editions etc). Linked that in place of the Goodreads one thus.
